# Multi-Tenant Enterprise Application Architecture and WSO2 Product Selection and Communication

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I am planning to implement enterprise application using wso2. I have following list of functions in my application and I have already chosen wso2 products for them.

Dynamic Business Process - WSO2-BPS 3.0.1
Dynamic Rule -- WSO2-BRS 2.0
Integration with LDAP, Sharepoint -- WSO2-IS 4.0
SOAP & REST Services -- WSO2-AS 5.0.1

My concerns are:

1) How can I share resources (configuration files, registries, etc) between products?

2) If I create Tenant in IS then How it will be available to other carbon products. can I use same tenant in other carbon products?

3) Can I externalize storage of Tenants?

4) Single sign on (logged in one product can also access other products)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this via our stratos Which will provide you to access to tenants from one product to another using centralised user store and you can use the Single sign on with Stratos which is by default available within products. You can play around with stratos from [this](http://wso2.com/cloud/stratos/).

If you download the local setup of stratos which will have all the WSO2 products as already pre-configured to run them in your private cloud. You can refer the README in the local setup pack for more information to run the setup.

Comment: I have downloaded Stratos and gone through README file. Everything is working fine but I am unable to browse management dashboard. I can see a message says "Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at appserver.stratos-local.wso2.com". I am using JDK1.7

Comment: If I browse http://appserver.stratos-local.wso2.com:9765/home/index.html it works. There are two button on this page and both are not working. I am unable to see login screen.